# How can I get next 10 or 20 row each API request with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have thousands of rows, but I don't want to use just `Users.ToList()` probably that is not efficient. I want to send just 20 or 30 row to API each request. Next 20 rows and next 20 rows I want to do like that, is it possible ?

Like Twitter or Instagram

What is the better solution in here?

Any video or article. I need some suggestion,

Thank you to everyone

**Note**: currently, I am using ASP.NET Core 5.0, I am using React Native as mobile development

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have your API endpoint accept page offset and page size parameters (how is up to you - query string, part of request body, etc).  You can then use the `IQueryable<T>` `.Skip` and `.Take` extension methods to return the requested set of rows:

```
var results = _dbContext.YourDbSet
    .Skip( pageOffset * pageSize )
    .Take( pageSize );
```

Answer (score 2):

Entity Framework has built-in support for paging.  You could implement it pretty easily like so:

```
private IQueryable<Users> GetPageOfUsers(this IQueryable<Users> query, int pageNumber, int pageSize = 20)
{
    // skip pages to get to the required page number
    query = query.Skip(pageSize * pageNumber);
    
    // take the number of entities to fill this page
    query = query.Take(pageSize);
    
    return query;
}
```

Then, you could call this extension method like so:

```
Users.GetPageOfUsers(0, 20).ToList();
```

It is worth noting that this method doesn't account for rows that may be inserted in the middle of a page between page requests; however, for a traditional table sorted by the primary key that is database-generated and auto-incrementing, this likely isn't a material issue.